# Group XML Content By Root Name

Tags: c#, xml, soap, wsdl, xelement

Due to my XML creating steps (Service WSDL File Step by Step Processing) I am getting this syntax of XML:

```
<auth>
    <appKey>ABCD567</appKey>
</auth>
<auth>
    <appSecret>456TYUU</appSecret>
</auth>
```

Host Service does not accept it, responsing <*one 'auth' element is missing*>, it accepts this:

```
<auth>
    <appKey>ABCD567</appKey>
    <appSecret>456TYUU</appSecret>
</auth>
```

How can I achive (grouping same roots with different elements after creating XML-not possible to change creating process) this syntax by XML Handling Codes.

some part of real code is like below:

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest>
            <auth>
                <appKey>***</appKey>
                <appSecret>***</appSecret>
            </auth>
            <categoryId>1002306</categoryId>
            <pagingData>
                <currentPage>0</currentPage>
                <pageSize>100</pageSize>
            </pagingData>
            <attributeList>
                <attribute>
                    <id>354189900</id>
                </attribute>
                <attribute>
                    <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                </attribute>
            </attributeList>
        </sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add how you compose the XML structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the question and the last Xml add, I have supposed that the xml is like :
**NOTE** : `sch` not exit in the posed XML, so i created it like `xmlns:sch=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""`

```
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""> 
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest xmlns:sch=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
            <auth>
                <appKey>ABCD567</appKey>
            </auth>
            <auth>
                <appSecret>456TYUU</appSecret>
            </auth>
            <categoryId>1002306</categoryId>
            <pagingData>
                <currentPage>0</currentPage>
            </pagingData>
            <pagingData>
                <pageSize>100</pageSize>
            </pagingData>
        </sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>;
```

To get the desired output by using **Linq to XML** especially [**XDocument**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=netcore-3.1) :

1 - Build grouped nodes if the xml have more than one :

```
var groupedItems = xDocument
                .Descendants(xn + "GetCategoryAttributesRequest")
                .Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    return x.Skip(1).Any() ? new XElement(x.Key, x.Descendants()) : x.First();
                }).ToList()
```

2 - Replace the olde xml :

```
xDocument.Descendants(xn + "GetCategoryAttributesRequest").First().ReplaceNodes(groupedItems);
```

The whole code :

```
string xml = @"
<env:Envelope
    xmlns:env=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/""> 
    <env:Header/>
    <env:Body>
        <sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest xmlns:sch=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
            <auth>
                <appKey>ABCD567</appKey>
            </auth>
            <auth>
                <appSecret>456TYUU</appSecret>
            </auth>
            <categoryId>1002306</categoryId>
            <pagingData>
                <currentPage>0</currentPage>
            </pagingData>
            <pagingData>
                <pageSize>100</pageSize>
            </pagingData>
        </sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>";

XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse(xml);
XNamespace xn = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";

var groupedItems = xDocument
    .Descendants(xn + "GetCategoryAttributesRequest")
    .Elements()
    .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
    .Select(x =>
    {
        return x.Skip(1).Any() ? new XElement(x.Key, x.Descendants()) : x.First();
    }).ToList();

xDocument.Descendants(xn + "GetCategoryAttributesRequest").First().ReplaceNodes(groupedItems);

Console.WriteLine(xDocument);
```

**Result**

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <env:Header />
  <env:Body>
    <sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest xmlns:sch="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchem
a-instance">
      <auth>
        <appKey>ABCD567</appKey>
        <appSecret>456TYUU</appSecret>
      </auth>
      <categoryId>1002306</categoryId>
      <pagingData>
        <currentPage>0</currentPage>
        <pageSize>100</pageSize>
      </pagingData>
    </sch:GetCategoryAttributesRequest>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I hope you find this update helpful.

Comment: regarding this small part of xml file your solution is perfect, but the real data has huge number of sub level nodes and different names of them to handle with this method. Wish there would be a general command of XML Culture to group all similar node names as it happens in SQL Group By Script...  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @biryaz can you update the question by adding the structure of the whole xml, this will help me to find the right solution.

Comment: @biryaz based on the last update of the question, check if my update is desired result.

Comment: we are very close to solution, problem is that, sub nodes are not being sorted here:            <anothersubnode>
                <pagingData>
                    <currentPage>0</currentPage>
                </pagingData>
                <pagingData>
                    <pageSize>100</pageSize>
                </pagingData>
            </anothersubnode>

Comment: @biryaz if we sorted from `anothersubnode`,so youshould deleted it from the xml.

Comment: realy there is no limit for sub nodes, if XML Culture has no-ready code for this operation, it would be impossible to solve this with logical approximities, I accepted your answer, altghoug there is still a waiting for any turn-key solution, thanks...